# React forms change

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a form that when I click a button, after replace with another form. I tried to use "Link to" for this, but after click the button the another form appears inside the first form. How to change my code to correct this?

My App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Login from "./Login";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Login />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My Login.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import CreateUser from "./CreateUser";
import GetUser from "./GetUser";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
  };

  change = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <br />
        Login
        <br />
        <br />
        <input
        name="email"
        placeholder='email'
        value={this.state.email}
        onChange={e => this.change(e)}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input
        name="password"
        type='password'
        placeholder='password'
        value={this.state.password}
        onChange={e => this.change(e)}
        />
        <br/ >
        <br/ >
        <Router>
        <div>
        <button onClick={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>
        <Link to="/GetUser">Login</Link>
        <Route exact path="/GetUser" component={GetUser}/>
        </ button>
        <br/ >
        <br/ >
        <button onClick={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>
        <Link to="/CreateUser">Sign Up</Link>
        <Route exact path="/CreateUser" component={CreateUser}/>
        </button>
        </div>
        </Router>
  </form>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click Login button, GetUser form appears inside the Login form, but I want the GetUser form to replace Login form.

Thx all,
Eduardo Gris

Answer (score 0):

The Route renders exactly where you put it in the component.  When it finds a match it replaces the Route with the component GetUser.  So whereever you want the GetUser to render is where you define the route.  There is no need to colocate Links and Routes as you are doing.

So for a common layout with a view that gets replaced with different components that view should be represented as a Switch and the first route that matches will be rendered: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md

In your case you need a parent component that has a switch statement that renders login as well as the other routes, you don't want to try to do everything in the Login component.